# Проверка запущенных процессов Python

Tags: python, ос, python-3.10, psutil

Создаю цикл, который проверяет систему на наличие запущенного процесса и в случаи его отсутствия запускает заново. Реализация проходит в два этапа. Проверка и выполнение действия (*либо запуск, либо игнорирование*). Для работы использую **условные операторы if**, **else**. Но проблема заключается в том, что программа игнорирует эту проверку и выполняет только одно из условий, не проверяя следующее. Код выглядит следующим образом:

```
import psutil
import os
import time

for start in psutil.process_iter():
    # создание переменной и присвоение ей start.name() не решает проблему
    if start.name() != "mspaint.exe":
        os.system("C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\mspaint.exe")
    else:
        time.sleep(100)
```

При компиляции открывается **Paint** даже если он был запущен ранее. То есть скрипт по неизвестной мне причине не проверяет запущена ли уже программа или все еще нет.

Comment: Вы данном цикле вы перебираете все процессы в системе и если каждый из них не mspaint запускаете mspaint. т.е. скажем у вас запущен chrome.exe. Цикл начинается, натыкается на chrome.exe, он очевидно не равен mspaint.exe и вы производите запуск. надо полностью менять логику, пройтись по всем процессам и например посчитать количество запущенных mspaint и уже после цикла если оно равно 0 запустить

Comment: ну или преобразовать список процессов в список имен и проверить на 'mspaint.exe' not in список

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
from psutil import process_iter
from os import startfile

processes_names = [process.name() for process in process_iter()]

paint = 'mspaint.exe'

if paint not in processes_names:
    startfile(paint)
```